# Copy and Paste Poses not working

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to copy the pose of the right arm to the left arm, but when I try copy and pasting it does this, does anyone know what is going on? I'm new to rigging so if you have any other tips they would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should check [Mirroring](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75848/how-do-i-make-x-axis-mirror-available-in-pose-mode).

> If you want to mirror your animation form the left side to the other
>   side during pose mode you just need to select the whole left side then
>   copy the pose with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

[image]

> After that press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to go to your right side
>   and finally press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to
>   paste the the X flipped pose, that way you'll have a perfect mirror of
>   both side

[image]

Or enable *X Axis Mirror* option.

[image]